# What does Java use for the datastore GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, datastore

In python, if you want to use the datastore you can import google app engine's ndb model to store data, but what does Java use for GAE's datastore?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's information best found in the existing documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent to NDB would be [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) ([sample code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/using-datastore-objectify)), though gae/j also supports standard Java data access libraries.  If you search for 'java objectify' you will find good info - it is my impression that it is quite popular on gae/j (though it didn't originate with google) and is the best supported option.